# How to get a FB Live stream key

Tags: facebook

For research purposes, I would like to know how to get the stream key of any Facebook Live stream. I've read tutorials on doing this for Twitch, and it seems straightforward, but I need it for Facebook.

Answer (score 1):

Go to your publishing tools, then video, then live and you should be able to see your key.

Read more here:
https://iag.me/socialmedia/broadcast-computer-facebook-live/